# google spreadsheet importxml, chop off part of query

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple ImportXml function in Google spreadsheet:

```
=ImportXml( "http://www.google.com/finance?q=0322.hk", "//span[@class='chr']" )
```

but it is giving me 2 cells of data, the cell direction underneath it is a =Continue(blah blah)... automatically placed by Google.

Here is the HTML code associated with this page. Looks like it has 2 items. I've replaced "<" & ">" with "(" & ")"

```
(span class="ch bld")(span class="chr" id="ref_673324_c")-0.45(/span)

(span class="chr" id="ref_673324_cp")(-2.02%)(/span)
```

How do I change my ImportXml function so that I'm only importing the "-0.45" without the "(-2.02%)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around... I put =NOEXPAND function infront of it and it works. but if anybody has another solution let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I've also found that the INDEX command works... useful too if you want the 2nd (-2.02%) item in the results.  One important note, though, is that you've got to first transpose the output of ImportXML or it won't work.

`=INDEX( TRANSPOSE (ImportXML (...)), {num})` where num is the desired result.